# Get the database ID (IDENTITY COLUMN) of newly created entity before context.SaveChanges()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

Is it possible to reserve an IDENTITY value for a to-be-added row in the database using Entity Framework?

In my override of `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`, I want to do something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    var affectedEntities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
        EntityState.Added |
        EntityState.Modified |
        EntityState.Deleted);

    foreach (var entry in affectedEntities)
    {
        var type = GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType());

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            // log the creation of the new entity into a log file
            // or a different table. For this, I need the newly
            // created entity's ID. Is it possible?
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(options);

    // if I check for ObjectState here, i.e. after SaveChanges, 
    // it won't work? Because once the changes are committed to the database
    // the newly added object's state would no longer remain
    // Added.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ask the database to preallocate the id's. You have 2 options

1. implement your own identity server
2. get the id's after the data has been written to the database

Here's a couple of examples of option 2. They both do the same thing - build a list of added items before the call to `SaveChanges()` and iterate over them after.

```
public interface IIDentifiable
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    List<IIDentifiable> addedObjects = GetNewEntries();
    int result = base.SaveChanges();
    foreach (IIDentifiable o in addedObjects)
    {
        //log o.id
    }
    return result;
}

private List<IIDentifiable> GetNewEntries()
{
    var result = (
        from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added
        select e.Entity)
        .OfType<IIDentifiable>()
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

the drawback of `IIDentifiable` is getting other details such as `Type` etc.

The second option is to do the same thing but use `dynamic` instead of `IIDentifiable`

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    List<dynamic> addedObjects = GetNewEntries();
    int result = base.SaveChanges();
    foreach (dynamic o in addedObjects)
    {
        //log o.id
        //log o.GetType()
    }
    return result;
}

private List<dynamic> GetNewEntries()
{
    var result = (
        from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added
        select e.Entity)
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Splendid. Basically, you're saying, "just cache stuff in lists and read from them later." Thank you. I implemented your suggestion and it worked. Awesome. Thanks so much. :-)

I just did a ToList(). I didn't use any interface because that would impose an explicit inheritance for my model objects from that interface since C# is not duck-typed.

I didn't use dynamic either because of the cost, and because all I wanted was there, their types known.

Thanks immensely.